# Bug? gradethis::grade_this_code() fails in `-code-check` chunk

Tags: r, learnr

Before I submit this as a bug report, I thought I'd toss it out to the community for verification...

Can anyone get `grade_this_code()` to work in a `-code-check` chunk?

The help file for `grade_this_code()` states the following:

> If `grade_this_code()` is called in a `-code-check` chunk and returns feedback, either passing or failing feedback, then the user's code is not executed. If you want the user to see the output of their code, call `grade_this_code()` in the -check chunk.

- When I call `grade_this_code()` in a `-check` chuck, it works as expected when an exercise is submitted.
- If I change the `-check` chunk into a `-code-check` chunk, the tutorial raises an error: "A problem occurred with the grading code for this exercise" when an exercise is submitted.
- If I change `grade_this_code()` to `grade_code()` in the `-code-check` chunk, everything works as expected when an exercise is submitted, but `grade-code()` is tagged as superseded by `grade_this_code()`

**learnr: version 0.11.5.9000**

**gradethis: version 0.2.14**

Here is a reproducible example that can be put in an RMarkdown file for execution.

````
---
title: "Reproducible"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
gradethis::gradethis_setup()
```

## Topic 1

Write the R code required to add two plus two:

```{r two-plus-two, exercise=TRUE}

```

```{r two-plus-two-solution}
2+2
```

<!-- The following works fine: note `-check` chunk with `grade_this_code()`

```{r two-plus-two-check}
gradethis::grade_this_code()
```
-->

<!-- The following works fine: note `-code-check` chunk with `grade_code()`

```{r two-plus-two-code-check}
gradethis::grade_code()
```
-->

<!-- the following fails with an error: `-code-check` chunk with `grade_this_code() -->

```{r two-plus-two-code-check}
gradethis::grade_this_code()
```
````

Comment: You're probably better off asking a question like this here:  https://community.rstudio.com/tag/gradethis, though it's not very active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Please simply use the `grade_code` further:) as a superseded function has a known better alternative, but the function itself is NOT going away.

First of all, the issue is most probably connected with `gradethis` package. I found out that the last issue in `gradethis` github repository is from Sep 2023 and there is no response yet. The introduction stated that It is in the development stage and is not yet on CRAN. The last commit to the repo was half a year ago. Summing up, there is a significant probability that the solution is almost abandoned.

Confirmed: When I add the a chunk with "-code-check" suffix (check without evaluation) then `gradethis::grade_this_code()` will raise an error.

You have an easy and reproducible example to present the error, so for sure, it is enough to be added as an issue on github. Please remember to add session info. However, be aware that there is a significant chance you will not get any response.

In the docs of `grade_this_code()`, we can find out, "If grade_this_code() is called in a -code-check chunk and returns feedback, either passing or failing feedback, then the user's code is not executed." so for sure, such functionality should be supported.

Please remember a superseded function has a known better alternative, but the function itself is NOT going away. So feel free to continue the use of the `grade_code()` function.

Error message:

```r
Loading required package: shiny
Loading required package: gradethis

Attaching package: ‘gradethis’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:learnr’:

    random_encouragement, random_praise


Listening on http://127.0.0.1:4532
#> grade_this({
#>     .message <- code_feedback()
#>     if (is.null(.message)) {
#>         if ("pass" %in% get(".__action")) {
#>             pass(get(".__correct"))
#>         }
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         if ("fail" %in% get(".__action")) {
#>             fail(get(".__incorrect"), hint = FALSE)
#>         }
#>     }
#>     invisible(NULL)
#> })(check_env)
Error in (function (e) {    on_error(e, this_env)})(structure(list(message = "Assertion on 'user_env' failed: Must be an environment, not 'NULL'.",     call = code_feedback()), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))): Assertion on 'user_env' failed: Must be an environment, not 'NULL'.
#> grade_this({
#>     .message <- code_feedback()
#>     if (is.null(.message)) {
#>         if ("pass" %in% get(".__action")) {
#>             pass(get(".__correct"))
#>         }
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         if ("fail" %in% get(".__action")) {
#>             fail(get(".__incorrect"), hint = FALSE)
#>         }
#>     }
#>     invisible(NULL)
#> })(check_env)
Error in (function (e) {    on_error(e, this_env)})(structure(list(message = "Assertion on 'user_env' failed: Must be an environment, not 'NULL'.",     call = code_feedback()), class = c("simpleError", "error", "condition"))): Assertion on 'user_env' failed: Must be an environment, not 'NULL'.
```

Comment: Appreciate the confirmation, @polkas.  I'm indeed continuing to use `grade_code()`. Will post as an issue on github `gradethis` site.